# Where can we find GitHub Apps Installation ID?

Tags: github, github-app

I'm setting up a GitHub App for ArgoCD authentication. The GitHub App setup is completed. But in ArgoCD it asks for GitHub App ID and GitHub App Installation ID. I could find the App ID from the GitHub App section itself. But I couldn't find the GitHub App Installation ID.

Is there a way to directly find GitHub App Installation ID from the GitHub website settings section? Or do we need to use GitHub API or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The

`InstallationID`

is the same ID that you can find in the GitHub endpoint:

`https://github.com/settings/installations/<ID>`

Comment: Okay got it. I was searching everywhere on the console instead of URL, thanks. And in my case, GitHub App was created under the an organization and the URL looks like this "https://github.com/organizations/<ORG-NAME>/settings/installations/<ID>". Its hard to find that from URL. Most of us are checking on the console.

Answer (score 18):

I'm making this answer a little more explanatory.

For GitHub Apps created under Organizations:

1. Go to the Organization settings
2. Click on 'GitHub Apps' under 'Third-party Access'
3. If there are multiple GitHub apps, choose your App and click on 'Configure'
4. Once your GitHub App is selected check the URL for obtaining 'GitHub App Installation ID'

The URL looks like this:

```
https://github.com/organizations/<Organization-name>/settings/installations/<ID>
```

Pick the **<ID>** part and that's your GitHub App Installation ID.

For GitHub Apps created under Repository, you can find this under repository settings.